# How to make an array from the deference between two arrays?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making an online shopping cart. so I want to update my total stock after confirming my products... I am able to catch the quantity from the user and i am able to catch my data from MYSQL. Now i want to make an array from the difference between my MYSQL quantity and user quantity and update my total stock after purchase...

My MYSQL ARRAY OUTPUT IS:

> print_r($qty);

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [stock] => 100 ) [1] => Array ( [stock] => 100 ) [2] => Array ( [stock] => 50 ) [3] => Array ( [stock] => 100 ) )
```

and

my user ARRAY OUTPUT IS:

> print_r ($_SESSION['productqty']);

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 [3] => 16 )
```

I want to make an array which will be like

```
Array ( [0] => 90 [1] => 88 [2] => 36 [3] => 84 )
```

This array is the difference between the two arrays and it will be updated in the MYSQLI Query...
I have Tried Everything.  Please Help me...

Comment: When you say you have tried everything, can you elaborate on the things you tried and did not work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indexes are equal the following code could work:

```
$remaining = [];

// iterate $qty rows and fill $remaining array
foreach($qty as $index => $entry) {
    $remaining[] = $entry['stock'] - $_SESSION['productqty'][$index];
}

var_dump($remaining);
```

**EDIT: Store updated stock in database**

Firstly it's necessary to select products' ids in your first query so that you're able to update them later. This step should result the following dump (apart from the correct ids)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 12, [stock] => 100 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 37, [stock] => 100 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 39, [stock] => 50 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 50, [stock] => 100 ) 
)
```

Now you can optimize your calculation by attaching the products' ids to your array:

```
remaining = [];

foreach($qty as $index => $entry) {
    $remaining[] = [
        'id_product' => $entry['id'],
        'stock' => $entry['stock'] - $_SESSION['productqty'][$index]
    ];
}
```

Now you're able to store your updated stocks:

```
foreach($remaining as $entry) {
    // Perform your SQL-Operation, something like:
    // UPDATE products SET stock = $entry['stock'] WHERE id = '$entry['id']
}
```

*Attention:* Please secure your application against SQL-Injections. 
Take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thank you, sir, so much... Can u also tell me the query to update these value in a database named CART in the  PRODUCT table in the STOCK column...

i meant it like in the array we got array(4) {
  [0]=> int(90)
  [1]=> int(88)
  [2]=> int(36)
  [3]=> int(84)
}

it should update the 90 in the STOCK column where ID = IN (' . implode(",", $product) . ') and so on..

Comment: Could your attach your query which fetches the data?

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cart');       
$query = 'SELECT stock FROM products WHERE id IN (' . implode(",", $product) . ')'; 
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

this to connect to mysqli

Comment: Sir i have stored my product ids in $product... 

so,
should i rename 

'id_product' => $entry['id'],
to
$product=> $entry['id'],
or 
implode(',',$product) => $entry['id'],

sry sir i am really a biginer in mysql codes

Comment: You shouldn't rename your variable if it stores more than the id. Imagine that each product provide a bundle of information: the product name, a category and the id with which we're able to find your record uniquely. In $products you'll save a collection of products, in $product just one. This approach makes it possible to write readable codes e.g. `foreach($products as $product)`.